# How to return real-time JSON without HTML code

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to make an API that will send back a real-time JSON. I am using NodeJS with ExpressJS, and Socket.io, and the problem is that res.send can not be sent more than one time; And, I really don't know how to send my (real-time) data without asking the refresh of my page.

Basically, I made a timer that changes the value every second. 
I also tried to send a file, but I can't use this method, because my iOS app is asking a JSON data without HTML code

```
setInterval( function() {
  var msg = Math.random().toString();
  io.emit('message', msg);
  console.log(msg);
  res.send(msg);
}, 1000);
```

Maybe, there is another framework than Express than I could use and could refresh my data automatically? The console.log line works well and my data is updated every 1000ms.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to use Web Sockets instead of raw HTTP requests.

Comment: So I cant use socket.io ?

Comment: you can use socket.io, but why would you res.send in a setInterval? the client should be connected to the socket.io server, and then will react accordingly when the server emits an event that you are listening for on the client.

Comment: Because the client and server is on the same point and res.send(msg) send all to the client because it only show a JSON. But after res.send, i can't modify the variable...